# Active directory searches with Anonymous bind

Tags: active-directory, jndi

I have a piece of code that perform search on active directory server, after bind operation. I am using LDAP protocol for binding and my code looks like this:

```
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "9000");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "9000");

            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + "nec.jp");
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
                        searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
        if (answer.hasMore())
           {
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalNameres);
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPasswd);
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                    final DirContext ctxForSerachedResult = new InitialDirContext(
                            env);
                    ctxForSerachedResult.close();

          }
```

My problem here is with configuration of AD server for performing search with an anonymous login user.

As per understanding for far, anonymous can be enabled by performing below shown steps:

a. Enable Anonymous LDAP operations by changing DsHeuristics attribute value.

b. Providing permissions to read the directory.

Referred Links:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverDS/thread/524a77fb-e819-497e-ae8a-c0fc43f1bba8
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326690

I had tried to ratify Active Directory setting using LDP.exe bind with anonymous login is successful as shown in below shown image:

But search operation is still not working as desired.

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously showing only a partial snippet of your and you do nto share what is NOT working.

What are you expecting.

We do have a [sample for JNDI](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Basic%20JNDI%20Search%20with%20Administration%20Account) that may help even though it is not an anonymous bind.

Comment: When search is performed output come as ----***Searching...
ldap_search_s(ld, "DC=nec,DC=jp", 2, "(samAccountName=dctestuser1)", attrList,  0, &msg)
Getting 0 entries:
----------- Where as in Active Directory server user with name "dctestuser1" exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting answer late.. Below shown changes in the code worked out :)

```
       DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
                    searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            if (answer.hasMore()) {
                /*
                 * Retrieving providerUrl and principal from the answer
                 * returned after search
                 */
                if (bindAlgoValue.equals(BINDANONYMOUS)) {
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, BINDSIMPLE);
                }
                final SearchResult res = answer.next();
                final String principalName = res.getNameInNamespace();
                final String providerUrl = res.getName();
                if (!res.isRelative()) {
                    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
                }
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPasswd);
                ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
                ctx.close();
                return true;
                // Code Fix End for BUG ID #1304
            }
```